# Android SDK : Playing video using mms protocol

Tags: android, video, streaming

Using the Android SDK, is it possible to play a video stream using the MMS protocol

I am streaming video from a PC using windows media.

I can use Windows Media Player to play the stream by just inputting the following URL in Windows Media Player

mms://192.168.223.194:8081

Is it possible to play the same stream using the Android SDK ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you are using old technology, or there are more efficient alternatives.

[MMS as a protocol has been deprecated for seven years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server). Android supports HTTP and RTSP streaming, and since Microsoft headed in that direction as well, it is unlikely that Android will ever support MMS-the-protocol.

Windows Media Player uses MMS URLs (`mms://`) to represent a whole family of possible protocols, including RTSP, MMS, and HTTP. Android appears to treat `mms://` as the equivalent of `http://` and may not attempt to connect via RTSP. The best answer is for you to figure out the correct URL for the desired protocol (e.g., `http://` or `rtsp://`). You could, if you wish, create some Android utility library that probes a server identified via an `mms://` URL, determines what the real protocol is, and then returns a properly-formatted URL for the desired protocol.