# play mms wmv video in android

Tags: java, android, mms

I saw this tutorial http://ffmpegandroid.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/below-blog-will-explain-steps-to-setup.html 
I compiled and get .so files. Now I want to play mms video on the screen.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a link that might be helpful 
<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529145/android-sdk-playing-video-using-mms-protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to play mms.
IJKPLAYER solved my problem (android,IOS)

```
 https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer
```

this lib use ffmpeg,so it supports not only mms but also all the formats that ffmpeg supports.